# MySql select statement works but not delete

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, sql-delete, subquery

```
SET @UserID_In = 1;
Select * FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETMain WHERE ETMain.UserID = @UserID_In
  AND ETMain.ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub WHERE ETSub.UserID = 
    ETMain.UserID AND ETSub.TransactionType = 'Buying' AND ETSub.CompleteDate IS NULL )
  AND ETMain.ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub WHERE ETSub.UserID =             
    ETMain.UserID );
```

Returns `34 15  Buying  1500    1428101231  1   2014-09-29 10:09:55`

but:

```
SET @UserID_In = 1;
Delete FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETMain WHERE ETMain.UserID = @UserID_In
   AND ETMain.ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub WHERE ETSub.UserID = 
       ETMain.UserID AND ETSub.TransactionType = 'Buying' AND ETSub.CompleteDate IS NULL )
   AND ETMain.ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub WHERE ETSub.UserID =                   
       ETMain.UserID );
```

Returns : 
`[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;` check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `AS ETMain WHERE ETMain.UserID = @UserID_In
   AND ETMain.ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID)` at line 1

Comment: CREATE TABLE `EarnedTransaction` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Points` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `TransactionType` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `LogNo` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CompleteDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Comment: Delete doesn't support aliases. -> http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this delete-query (without alias for the "delete-table"):

```
SET @UserID_In = 1;
DELETE FROM EarnedTransaction 
      WHERE UserID = @UserID_In
        AND ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) 
                    FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub 
                   WHERE ETSub.UserID = UserID 
                     AND ETSub.TransactionType = 'Buying' 
                     AND ETSub.CompleteDate IS NULL)
        AND ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) 
                    FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub 
                   WHERE ETSub.UserID = UserID );
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the following simplifications. At some point you probably meant something different.

Original, formatted:

```
SET @UserID_In = 1;
DELETE FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETMain WHERE ETMain.UserID = @UserID_In
AND ETMain.ID = (
     SELECT MAX(ID)
     FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub
     WHERE ETSub.UserID = ETMain.UserID
     AND ETSub.TransactionType = 'Buying'
     AND ETSub.CompleteDate IS NULL )
AND ETMain.ID = (
     SELECT MAX(ID)
     FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub
     WHERE ETSub.UserID = ETMain.UserID );
```

The first subquery AND the second subquery reduce to the first. Maybe something like an OR-ELSE was meant?

```
SET @UserID_In = 1;
DELETE FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETMain WHERE ETMain.UserID = @UserID_In
AND ETMain.ID = (
     SELECT MAX(ID)
     FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub
     WHERE ETSub.UserID = @UserID_In
     AND ETSub.TransactionType = 'Buying'
     AND ETSub.CompleteDate IS NULL );
```

Now the main alias is not needed (if using the @UserID_In)

```
SET @UserID_In = 1;
DELETE FROM EarnedTransaction WHERE UserID = @UserID_In
AND ID = (
     SELECT MAX(ID)
     FROM EarnedTransaction AS ETSub
     WHERE ETSub.UserID = @UserID_In
     AND ETSub.TransactionType = 'Buying'
     AND ETSub.CompleteDate IS NULL );
```

Then the subset alias, and removal of double condition on UserID:

```
SET @UserID_In = 1;
DELETE FROM EarnedTransaction WHERE ID = (
     SELECT MAX(ID)
     FROM EarnedTransaction
     WHERE UserID = @UserID_In
     AND TransactionType = 'Buying'
     AND CompleteDate IS NULL );
```

Here the subquery is easily checked.